# Cannot sample values of a trigonometric function

Tags: python

I have a problem with my code.
So i try to represent the sampled values of a function 'sin(t^3)/2^tan(t)' for
t between 0 and 1.5 and frequency fs=50Hz.

I have created a function 'sampleFunction' which takes as parameters the string which represents the trigonometric function,beginning of the interval,end of interval and the frequency.
I create tVector(0,0.02,0.04,..,1.48)
Then I take the elements of tVector and use them to evaluate the string and put the result in another vector y
I return both y and tVector

But I encounter a problem when i run it saying 'y' is not defined
This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def sampleFunction(functionString,t0,t1,fs):
      tVector=np.arange(start=t0, stop=t1, step=1/fs, dtype='float')
      t=t0
      for i in range(0,len(tVector)):
         t=tVector[i]
         y[i]=eval(functionString)
      return y,tVector

 t0=0
 t1 =1.5
 fs=50
 thold=.1
 functionString='math.sin(t**3)/2**math.tan(t)'
 y,t=sampleFunction(functionString,t0,t1,fs)
 plt.plot(t,y)
 plt.xlabel('time')
 plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code in the following way:

```py
def sampleFunction(functionString,t0,t1,fs):
      tVector=np.arange(start=t0, stop=t1, step=1/fs, dtype='float')
      t=t0
      y = np.zeros( tVector.shape )
      for i in range(0,len(tVector)):
         t=tVector[i]
         y[i]=eval(functionString)
      return y,tVector
```

However, this is not good python. There are a couple of issues:

1. You should use vectorized operations.
2. You should avoid `eval` like the plague. This has security implications.

For vectorized operations, simply do:

```py
def sampleFunction(functionString,t0,t1,fs):
      t = np.arange(start=t0, stop=t1, step=1/fs, dtype='float')
      y = eval(functionString)
      return y, t
```

and call it as:

`sampleFunction('np.sin(t**3)/2**np.tan(t)', 0, 10, 100)`

This is much faster (especially for large arrays)

Finally, the vectorized form is only a single line long. You probably don't need the extra function.

Comment: Oh thanks man!Now it works and it plots exactly the graph i needed.What alternative is there for eval?

Answer (score 0):

When running the above code, you should have gotten an error message saying, in the end, "*name 'y' is not defined*". If you look at your function definition, you will see that it really isn't. You cannot passing a value to y[i] without defining y first! The following line before the "for" loop fixes that particular problem:

```
y = [None] * len(tVector)
```

The code will run fine after that correction.

But: why do you want to pass a function string when you can pass a function? Functions, in Python, are first-class-objects!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the allocation of the 'y' variable as [Harold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55881584/4039619) is saying.

However, there are multiple ways of achieving what you are doing and the `eval` function is, unless you have a **very** good reason, the absolute worst. Maybe consider one of the possible examples below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def sampleFunction(functionString,t0,t1,fs):
      tVector=np.arange(start=t0, stop=t1, step=1/fs, dtype='float')
      t=t0
      y = [float]*len(tVector) # <------------------- Allocate 'y' variable
      for i in range(0,len(tVector)):
         t = tVector[i]
         y[i]=eval(functionString)
      return y,tVector


t0=0
t1 =1.5
fs=50
thold=.1

# Your code
functionString = 'math.sin(t**3)/2**math.tan(t)'
y, t = sampleFunction(functionString,t0,t1,fs)
plt.plot(t, y, color='cyan')

# Using the 'map' built-in function
t = np.arange(start=t0, stop=t1, step=1./fs, dtype='float')
y = map(lambda ti: 0.9*math.sin(ti**3)/2**math.tan(ti), t)
plt.plot(t, y, color='magenta')

# Using Numpy's 'sin' and 'tan'
t = np.arange(start=t0, stop=t1, step=1./fs, dtype='float')
y = 0.8*np.sin(t**3)/2**np.tan(t)
plt.plot(t, y, color='darkorange')

# Using 'list comprehensions'
t = np.arange(start=t0, stop=t1, step=1./fs, dtype='float')
y = [ 0.7*math.sin(ti**3)/2**math.tan(ti) for ti in t]
plt.plot(t, y, color='darkgreen')

plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.show()
```

The result is:

[image]